# AndroidManifest.xml - specified for property 'manifest' does not exist

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle

This is the error I'm getting and one that is seemingly unfixable from what I've been searching through on StackOverflow.

```
Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':checkDebugManifest'.
> File '/Users/wasimsandhu/AndroidStudioProjects/Conjugation/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' 
specified for property 'manifest' does not exist.
```

I keep getting this error every time I rebuild the project or sync Gradle files. I have tried solutions in various other threads here to no avail.

Here is my app/build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        // removed for this post
    }
}

compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wsandhu.conjugation"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.5"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'de.cketti.library.changelog:ckchangelog:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.0.1'
}
```

And here is the build.gradle file in the root directory:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wsandhu.conjugation"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.5"
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wsandhu.conjugation" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is the gradle wrapper file, in case that is important:

```
#Mon Nov 17 20:04:45 PST 2014
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip
```

I apologize in advance for the bad formatting or if anything is unclear.

Comment: `build.gradle` in the root directory should not use the `android` plugin. Can you try to remove the plugin and all related code and see if anything changes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove this chunk of code from your build.gradle in the root directory

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

and

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wsandhu.conjugation"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.5"
    }
}
```

As it says that:

**// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong in the individual module build.gradle files**

Meaning this line of code goes to in the gradle file inside your app folder.

Try making your top gradle file like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I had the same problem before. So I think this will solve your case.

Comment: This is why I'm still a beginner. Thanks!

Comment: No prob mate. :) Happy Coding and Goodluck!

Comment: for me the solution was this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407520/checkdebugmanifest-failed-file-specified-for-property-manifest-does-not-ex